# Очистка переменной со ссылкой

Tags: php

Есть переменная:

```
private static $var = &$_SESSION['test']; //пример тестовый(не работает)
```

и я хочу очистить её в методе этого же класса, например:

```
public static function testf()
{
....
}
```

как очистить данную переменную так, чтобы значение `&$_SESSION['test']` осталось не тронутым а переменная `self::$var` была равна `NULL`?

Comment: Предположу, что можно значение временно сбросить во временную переменную `$tmp`, уничтожить `$var`, а потом в сессию взять значение из `$tmp` ну и потом `unset($tmp);` еще

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, спасибо, вообще не так вас понял вначале:)

Comment: только я наверное погорячился. вместо `unset(self::$var)` нужно все же делать `self:$var = null`. Потому, что  `unset` уничтожит переменную. а вам, как я понял, нужно просто `null` было значение

Comment: А не легче убрать ссылку? ради чего такой кастыль?

Comment: @Naumov ну а если приспичило? =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Таки нужен unset или присвоение другой ссылки! Любое (нессылочное) присвоение изменит содержимое оригинальной переменной. См. пример в моём ответе.

Comment: @LittleByte в целом да. даже надо сделать линк переменной на другую переменную, содержащую `null` тогда всё получится..... вот пример наглядный  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4fmm-227g

Answer (score 1):

```
private static $var = $_SESSION['test'];

public static function testf()
{
    ....
    self::$var = null;
}
```

скорее всего так удаляем ссылку и присваиваем null переменной. Есть в программирование понятие рефакторинга простыми словами это тогда когда приложение разрабатываеться так, что бы, оно позваляло делать то что надо. Если оно не позволяет это делать, смотришь более глубоко, и делаешь так что бы оно(приложение) позваляло и работало. А работу можно и даже нужно проверить unit тестом после разработки запускаешь unit тестирование, если приложение прошло тест то всё норм, можно пить шампанское, если нет то опять занимаешься рефакторингом... и т.д. и т.п. В общем таким образом мы получаем "красивый код" с которым приятно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Надо очистить ссылочную переменную или перенацелить ссылочную переменную на другую переменную.

```
<?php

$a = 1000;
$b = null;
$r = &$a;
echo $r, "\n"; // r is a

$r = 1100;
echo $a, "\n"; // r is a

unset($r);
//или так: $r = &$b;
echo $a, "\n"; // r is not a
```

Пример выводит 1000, 1100, 1100.

Полезное чтиво:

- http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.unset.php
- http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/references-tutorial/

Comment: Да, только следуя из этого и того, что хотел автор у вас 1) в результате   `$_SESSION['test']` перетрется другими данными, что автор делать НЕ хотел и 2) вы уничтожите переменную, которую, возможно, потом автор захочет использовать еще раз

Comment: Я вас не понимаю @АлексейШиманский. Оригинал не затрется. Автор хотел очистить переменную.

Comment: в результате ваших манипуляций (предположим что $a это $_SESSION['test']) будет следущее: `echo $r, "\n"; // r is a

$r = 1100;
echo $a, "\n"; // r is a`, в результате `$a` будет равно 1100, а нужно было, чтобы в `$a` оставалось `1000` ..... а `unset` у статической переменной вообще нельзя сделать

Comment: Потрясающе! Присвоение 1100 в примере было только для демонстрации как работает ссылка. Не надо это копировать в код, тогда оригинал не пострадает. ))) Ок, для *статического свойства* остается второй предложенный вариант — присвоение другой ссылки.

Comment: так а зачем приводить пример как работает ссылка, если автор знает итак? и в результате просмотра вашего примера будет непонятно почему так делается и почему происходит изменение значение переменной на которую ссылались.. Сделали бы корректно сразу)

Comment: Я воздержусь делать предположения насчет знаний автора.  Добра вам!